Не работает yarn create с @latest
https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/getting-started
Пытаюсь использовать команду yarn create @eslint/config@latest и получаю следующий вывод в консоли:
yarn create v1.22.22
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Installed "@eslint/create-config@1.2.0" with binaries:
- create-config
[#######################################################################] 71/71"C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\create-config@latest" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
error Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\create-config@latest
Arguments:
Directory: C:\Users\User\MyProjects\test
Output:
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/create for documentation about this command.
Проблема в @latest, если я введу yarn create @eslint/config, то всё заработает.
Это так и должно быть, или что-то не так с моим Yarn? И почему на сайте eslint предлагают использовать @latest, если он не работает как ожидается?
Знаю, что это указывает на использование последней версии, но почему это описано в докуметации к eslint, если оно не работает? Может, у меня что-то не так?
